# How to move a window with keyboard on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way (hot-key, tools or whatever) to move a window with keyboard on a Mac?

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/68811/what-keyboard-shortcuts-move-resize-and-maximize-windows-under-mac-os-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a 3rd party app. I prefer [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/). [MercuryMover](http://www.heliumfoot.com/mercurymover/), [MondoMouse](http://www.atomicbird.com/mondomouse/) and [Zooom](http://coderage-software.com/zooom/index_green/index.html) will do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

An app I developed, [Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout), also supports moving and resizing windows via the keyboard, as well as a bunch of other window management tools.