# Can I change the position of a window on OSX using my arrow keys?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to move a window with keyboard on a Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/167099/how-to-move-a-window-with-keyboard-on-a-mac)

I need the ability to position and resize windows accurately (e.g., move or resize by one pixel).

I know that in Windows, I can move a window using the arrow keys.

Is there any way to do this in OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need third party software to do this, e.g. [MercuryMover](http://www.heliumfoot.com/mercurymover/).

[SizeUp](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) is similar to `Windows-Arrow` shortcuts in Windows 7.