# Windows 7 resize shortcuts to Mac OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, shortcuts, window-manager

In Windows 7, it's possible to do various resize operations by dragging windows: drag window to top of screen, and it'll be enlarged to fill whole screen. Drag it to left edge and it'll cover left side (50%), same for right edge. Also, bonus points: resizing window to top of screen keeps width but changes height to cover screen from top to bottom. In my opinion, that's way better than keyboard shortcuts.

**Is there a way (with or without installing 3rd party software, preferably free) to do this in Mac OS X (10.6)?**

Related, but not same: [What keyboard shortcuts move, resize, and maximize windows under Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/68811/what-keyboard-shortcuts-move-resize-and-maximize-windows-under-mac-os-x) I also checked out programs in answers, but all of those are for keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible without 3rd party software.

---

[Cinch](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/) is similar to Windows 7. [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) is its more powerful, more complicated and keyboard-oriented cousin.

---

An alternative is [Arrange](http://www.trifleapps.com/Applications/Arrange.html).

Comment: Looking good, especially Arrange (both dragging and keyboard shortcuts). Unfortunately not free, but fortunately cheap. I'll wait if someone else has something to say before accepting this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Better Touch Tool](http://www.boastr.de/) provides Win 7 and much more functionality. It is donationware.

[Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) also provides this functionality but is a much richer (that's secret code for "complicated") app.

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorites is HyperDock. Its not free, but it is very powerful, but I think you can get a trial.

http://hyperdock.bahoom.com/