# Open minimized window (deminimize) with keyboard shortcut in macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I open/show/deminimize a minimized window on macOS Sierra 10.12.5?

[There](http://osxdaily.com/2013/03/22/5-simple-window-management-keyboard-shortcuts-to-improve-workflow-in-mac-os-x/) [are](https://superuser.com/questions/196141/keyboard-shortcut-to-unhide-or-unminimize-a-window-in-os-x) [many](http://www.macworld.com/article/1152366/os-x/commandtabminimizedwindows.html) sites talking about `CMD + tab` and the press the `option`-key, before releasing. Yeah - that works to an extend. But first of all - I don't know that the window is minimized, when I `CMD + tab` to it. So whenever I come across a minimized application, then I first `CMD + tab` to it, - then realize it is minimized. And because I don't want to move my hands from `asdf` and `jkl;`, then I afterwards press `CMD + tab`, then `CMD + shift + tab + option + release CMD`. FFS Apple! While I'm already angry, I might as well ask. What is the advantage of making it this way!? Is that how people prefer it to be? Do they think: 'I'll just `CMD + tab` to this application... Not because I need to do anything with any of the open windows. No, no, no, no, no!! Almost no one uses the open windows of running applications!'

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/718600/keyboard-shortcut-to-maximize-current-window-application-in-osx/718843#answer-718843) suggest making a shortcut to 'Zoom'. It worked previously - but one of the latest OS-updates made it stop working *sigh*. The answer does start like this: `Assign a shortcut for the Zoom menu item (or whatever it's called in your locale) from System Preferences`.

So my question is: Where do I find this `locale` and figure out what to write instead of Zoom?

And to all the sorry souls, who's also looking for an answer to this. This is the other things I've tried:

**Attempt1) Try Witch**

[Witch](https://manytricks.com/witch/) actually has the command that I want. AND it's possible to assign it a shortcut-key:

[image: Withc-deminimize-shortcut]

... BUT. When I use that shortcut, then it opens it taking 2-seconds or so:

[image]

It must be a bug. I can't find any options to change that speed. Close, but no cigar. 
I've also tried to replace the `CMD + tab` with Witch' function (which initially is `option + tab`. But that doesn't deminimize the window either, when choosing the application.

**Attempt2) Use Spectacle**

[The same](https://superuser.com/questions/718600/keyboard-shortcut-to-maximize-current-window-application-in-osx/718843) answer suggest using `Fullscreen` or `Center` from Spectacle. That doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Witch's support got back to me super-quickly. It seems to be an Apple-feature, that if I do something with the dock and hold in the SHIFT-key, - then it will happen in grandma-tempo.

So by switching the shortcut-key to something that didn't involve shift, then it's working. Ahhhhh! FINALLY!

**Addition** And it just came to my attention, that if you press `CMD + h` (hide) instead of `CMD + m` (minimize), then it shows the window when you `CMD + tab` to it.

**Addition1** And when installing Witch, - be sure to log out and log in afterwards. After I did that (48 hours after installation), then it started working exactly as I wanted it to.

**Addition2** After a while, I stopped using Witch, and started using BetterTouchTool instead. So I rarely minimize anything any longer. I have setup shortcuts, so when I press:

- `CTRL` + `CMD` + `1`, then Chrome opens.
- `CTRL` + `CMD` + `2`, then Firefox opens.
- `CTRL` + `CMD` + `2`, then Terminal opens.
- ... Etc.

So I just went through the 10 programs I swap between the most, and setup those shortcuts. You do this under the 'Keyboard'-section, setting up a shortcut and then the assigned action is 'Launch Application' (and then you choose the path).

It's awesome!! I've used it for more than a year now. Never going back to `CMD` + `Tab`. I rarely use it any longer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "Cycle Windows" instead of "Cycle apps", this way it will behave just like the tab switcher but also deminimize apps.