# Maximize window in Microsoft Word for Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

How do I set the maximum window size for Microsoft Word For Mac? I can do this for individual documents. For eg. if I resize the document 'Right.doc' and open it the next time it opens at the same size but when I open a new document say 'left.doc' it opens at the old default size. 'Option + Green button' doesn't change anything and I have to manually resize the window.

Comment: Do you want full screen for every Word window? Or just the same size for every window? Does this question and the answers there help: http://superuser.com/questions/68811/what-keyboard-shortcuts-move-resize-and-maximize-windows-under-mac-os-x?

Comment: No this questions doesn't help. All software has to be paid for. I tried using Spectacle. But Spectacle doesn't have a command to maximize only command to full screen and I don't want to full screen I only want to maximize

Answer (score 0):

**RightZoom** might do what you want. It is a free app that is supposedly working only up to OS X 10.9, but I have just run it on El Capitan and Yosemite and it appears to work. (I am not affiliated with the tool or its creator in any way.)

Once you maximize a document in Word, when you reopen in Word it fills the full screen.

You set a hotkey and the window fills the screen without going full screen, like in Windows. You can even limit it to one program only.

[image: RightZoom screenshot]

More info here: http://www.blazingtools.com/right_zoom_mac.html

Download here: http://www.blazingtools.com/downloads.html#RightZoom