# Are there any keyboard shortcuts to minimize or maximize a window in macOS?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Every time I want to minimize or maximize the window, I need to move the mouse to the top left corner and click the minimize button or maximize button. Are there any keyboard shortcuts to minimize or maximize a window in macOS? I referred to [What keyboard shortcuts move, resize, and maximize windows under Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/68811/what-keyboard-shortcuts-move-resize-and-maximize-windows-under-mac-os-x). It answers how to maximize the window, but it doesn't answer how to minimize it, so it only solves one of my two questions.

Comment: I know on Windows there is a hotkey of Windows + ↓ to minimise, is that key or an equivalent using the Apple command key not present in MacOS?

Comment: Hi @Mokubai, are you saying Cmd ⌘ + ⌄?

Comment: If you say Cmd ⌘ + ⌄, I just tried it and it doesn't work

Comment: If ⌄ is your down arrow on the keyboard then yes it is what I mean. I have seen that key combination on Windows and some Linux desktops, I guess MacOS just has to be "different".

Comment: Yes @Mokubai, ⌄ is the down arrow on my keyboard

Comment: Looks like macOS is different from the rest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fn+F does the job! It will maximize and minimize to a full-screen application.

Comment: Maximizing and full-screen is not the same thing. For example, if application A have two maximized windows in the same desktop, Cmd-` can switch between them. However, Cmd-` won't work for two full-screen windows of the same application.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2469/mac:

Maximize a window: Double-click the application's title bar to maximize the window (there doesn't appear to be a keyboard shortcut).

Minimize a window: Press Command-M.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default shortcut for maximizing (`Zoom` menu title), [but you can add one.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372719/maximize-window-shortcut)

`⌘` + `M` is the default for the `Minimize` menu title (you can adjust this the same way as the maximize, described above).

The free [Rectangle app](https://rectangleapp.com/) can handle Maximize and various other screen splitting settings, but not minimize.